# What to do if Geometry Dash doesn't startup?

Tags: geometry-dash

This has been happening for 3 days now. I start the game and nothing happens, all it does is to inform me that I am in Offline Mode (I have limited internet access, so I cannot reinstall the game either). On the first day, I just went into online mode for a bit and it worked. The second day I had to restart my PC but today, none of them worked. I tried the following:

- Verify the files
- Search all the internet for solutions
- Start through steam, through `steam://rungameid/322170` and through `C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Geometry Dash\GeometryDash.exe`
- Reinstall the monitor drivers, just in case it had started.
- Try to find out if it didn't even start, and it didn't
- Run it in compatibility mode

I also found a solution to use by going to `%localappdata%\GeometryDash` and deleting `CCGameManager.dat`, but I prefer not to because I have an un-backupped 20k-objects level.

Please help me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If you are reading this, DO NOT RETRY TO OPEN YOUR GAME! Read the FULL post first.

While I was writing this question, I thought that `CCLocalLevels.dat` might be the local levels. So, I copied all the `CC*.dat` files and pasted them in a different folder. Then I deleted all the files in the GeometryDash AppData folder and restarted the game. The `CCLocalLevels.dat` file changed from 30MB to 1KB and that was the most stressful moment of my last 5 years. I stopped for a bit to think clearly:

If there is both a `CCLocalLevels.dat` and a `CCLocalLevels2.dat`, then the second one might be some kind of backup. Now, what I think that happens is that the second file gets overwritten every time you save, create or delete a level. Later, I started to search for how to fix the broken files, as the only backup I had at that moment was `CCLocalLevels2.dat`, but it still didn't work properly, provided that the game deleted the file on its own.

After some research, I came across this cool little software that fixes your GD files ([link](https://github.com/WEGFan/Geometry-Dash-Savefile-Fix/releases/download/v1.1.1/GDSavefileFix_v1.1.1.exe)). I instantly understood what it did so I copied the `CCLocalLevels2.dat`, the `CCGameManager.dat`, and the `CCGameManager2.dat` files and pasted them in the `%localappdata%\GeometryDash` folder. **Make sure not to cut them, that's how I lost my first set of backup files**. The program then told me that it successfully repaired all the files, but it didn't find the `CCLocalLevels.dat` file (the lost one).

Now, if you try to download the software and paste the broken files in there (make sure to keep backup), the game should start and your levels will still be there. If you don't want this to happen ever again, just make sure to back up your files on the cloud (or locally) and close the game by its own X button (in the main menu). What happened to me was to close the game using `Alt+F4` or just turn off my laptop without closing the game first. All this problem started from my laptop not having a battery (it's broken. I only have its charger).

Comment: Hey Ath.Bar, would you like to mark your answer as accepted?

Comment: Yes, thank you for reminding me. I wanted to do it 2 days after I posted but I wasn't able to access the internet for some days...